# storing socket connections in a javascript array and using Array.find() on the array behaves unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

In the following code after the **sockets.find()** statement the console.log("AFTER") statement is not executed

```
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var this_socket = socket;
    socket.username = null;
    socket.gameSessionName = null;
    socket.update_usernames = false;
    sockets.push(socket);  // sockets is AN ARRAY

    socket.on('loaded', function (data) {
        var previous_socket;
        socket.username = data.username;
        socket.status = 'BROWSE_PLAYERS'; // WAIT_FOR_ACCEPT, PLAYING
        console.log("BEFORE");    

        previous_socket = sockets.find (function(s) {           
            return false;
        });

        console.log("AFTER"); // THIS IS STATEMENT IS NOT EXECUTED
        ....
```

If the socket.find() code is commented as shown below then the console.log("AFTER") statement is printed.

```
        // previous_socket = sockets.find (function(s) {            
        //  return false;
        // });
```

It looks like the **sockets.find(...)** statement has side effects. How to solve this issue.

Comment: `sockets.filter` not `sockets.find`

Comment: Where is `sockets.find` declared?

Comment: @lujcon  Thanks. Overlooked that find() was declared in ES6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find